# Updating secondary SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list that users use in an app, I now need to create a new list that tracks if the SharePoint list was active (if the app was used),  maybe using a few columns that I can use to check if any items were created for the day, if no items were created, than send an email to the owner to advise that no Items were created using a scheduled flow.